# Storing JSP Tags in a Database

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, tags, jsp-tags

I have a requirement to store jsp content in a oracle database. I retrieve it from the database and store it in a string and output it by setting escapeXML to false which renders the html.

```
<c:out value="${myProfileForm.skinElement.footerContent}" escapeXml="false"/>
```

This works fine except for tags which end up resolving as html and not tags for example:

```
        <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${displayLinks=='true'}">
            <jsp:include page="header-myprofile.jsp" />
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${displayLinks=='false'}">
            <jsp:include page="header-no-menu.jsp" />
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>       
            <jsp:include page="header-myprofile.jsp" />
        </c:otherwise>  
    </c:choose>
```

Is there a way to store jsp tags in a database?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of storing JSP in database you can achieve the same thing by using a Templating Engine like [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or [FreeMarker](http://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffreemarker.sourceforge.net%2F&ei=y7pTTeDZKcaJhQe7uPT9CA&usg=AFQjCNGib2rcnIxKwpN-I35K_2vT8UV9nA).

Comment: Thanks. Seems like the long term solution. In the short term I have to use a jsp